# What is it called when both price action and RSI are achieving lower lows?

Tags: stock-analysis, stock-valuation

I've been analyzing $NVTS and I'm confused on the RSI/Price Action. The price is going down and so is the RSI so their going in the same direction downward...What is it called when both price action and RSI are achieving lower lows? Obviously not good but is there a term to describe it?

Thank you